# Create empty native C++ byte* in C# to PInvoke with

Tags: c#, marshalling

I need to create a binary blob of empty data to PInvoke a native C++ dll that needs a unsigned char* of nulls.

The native C++ program is expecting a structure of data, and there's a nulled area of bytes in the middle, but in C# I can't just make a struct with an initialized byte[] in the middle.

My struct in C++ looks like this

```
struct myStruct
{
    byte command;
    byte returncode;
    void* Source (a pointer to a string, rather a null term char*)
    void* Destination (same thing)
    byte filler [99]
    byte options;
}
```

I've already figured that I can take a string and convert it to an array of bytes using `myStruct.Source = (void*)Marshal.StringtToGlobalAnsi(source)` (correct me if I'm wrong).
But I don't know how to fill out that empty array of bytes in the middle.

This is my C# struct so far.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
unsafe struct Trans_s
{
    public byte command;
    public byte returnCode;

    public void* pSource;
    public void* pDest;
    public byte* filler;
    public byte options;
}
```

Comment: There is no 'nulled area of bytes' in the middle, only the debugger will make it look like that.  Standard behavior when it tries to display the value of a pointer.  Declare the fields either string (if it is really a zero terminated string) or IntPtr.  You'll have to marshal an IntPtr yourself, use the Marshal class.

Comment: On the recieving end, it expects this filler in the middle. I needs this filler in the middle. Without the filler in the middle, it addresses options wrong.

Comment: You must be talking about "filler" at the end.  It is a byte[], not a byte*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the array of bytes, you need to mark the field in the C# struct as a byvalarray. The default marshaller uses LPArray if you do not.

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 99)]
public byte[] filler;
```

You need to allocate the memory for filler when you create an instance of the struct.

Comment: I like @Ben Voigt suggestion. Would it be best if I do both

Comment: You can do both if you want, however, if you use the built in marshalling functionality you can eliminate unsafe code completely. For example, your pSource and pDest can be declared as strings, marked with the correct attribute, eg `UnmanagedType.LPStr`, or `BStr`/`LPWStr`, depending on the string format in the C++ library.

Comment: How would I marshal a FBYTE8 as, which I think comes down to a (single byte) char? Or an BYTE which I think is an unsigned char.

Comment: No I need a pointer to a string. Not a string itself. This won't work.

Comment: the `LPStr` is a pointer to an ANSI string (1 byte per character)

Comment: Your idea worked splendidly (can't use fixed with safe code). So now all my code is "safe". Nice.

Answer (score 2):

No, the C++ code doesn't expect an `unsigned char*` of nulls.  It expects that many padding bytes inside the struct.

The [C# `fixed` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx) might help you here.